# Renaming files, new name from list - Python

Tags: python, file, rename, file-rename

```
def thing():
    os.chdir("D:\Desktop\SoundTracks")
    root = "D:\Desktop\SoundTracks"
    temp_track_titles = []
    for f in os.listdir():
        temp_track = TinyTag.get(root + "\\" + f)
        temp_track_titles.append(temp_track.title)
        #print(temp_track.title)
        #new_name = '{}-{}{}'.format(temp_track.title,temp_track.album,f_ext)
        #os.rename(f,new_name)
    temp_track_titles = [''.join(c for c in s if c not in string.punctuation) for s in temp_track_titles]
    #print(temp_track_titles)
    for i in temp_track_titles:
        for f in os.listdir():
            new_name = '{}{}'.format(i,'.mp3')
            os.rename(f,new_name)
            temp_track_titles.remove(i)

while True:
    thing()
```

I want to rename files based on the list temp_track_titles.
[image: the error]

[image: what the temp_track.titles looks like]

[image: what the Soundtracks Folder looks like]

I apologize if confusing. I have looked around for hours, and could not find a solution. Basically I want to "map" the names from the temp_tracks_titles list to the files from the folder. For example, name #3 from the list should become the name of the file #3 from the folder.

Comment: Why dont you rename directly in the first loop, that you commented out ?

Answer (score 0):

1.) A `while True:` loop will repeatedly rename your files for as long as the script is running.  Are you *sure* this is what you want to do?

2.) You should be iterating through each file in `os.listdir()` exactly once.  Currently you are iterating the directory for each name that is in `temp_track_titles` list.

3.) Each time you `remove` an actively iterating object, you are skipping to the next iteration directly which messes up your expected order.  Do not remove objects of a collection as you iterate through a collection.

Following these comments, you will want to reformat your code thus:

```
def thing():
    root = "D:\Desktop\SoundTracks"
    os.chdir(root)
    for f in os.listdir():
        temp_track = ''.join(c for c in TinyTag.get(root + "\\" + f) if c not in string.punctuation)
        new_name = '{}.mp3'.format(temp_track)
        os.rename(f, new_name)

thing()
```